# How to change page title without changing tab bar item's title as well?

Tags: objective-c, title, uitabbaritem

I want to be able to change the page's title without affecting the tab bar's title. My current implementation is as follows:

```
//Setting page and UITabbar title in app delegate
ForYouViewController *fuvc = [[ForYouViewController alloc]init];
fuvc.title = @"Questions";
UITabBarItem *tempTabBarItem1 = [[UITabBarItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Questions" image:nil tag:QUESTIONTAB_INDEX];
```

Before clicking on questions tab

[image]

```
//After changing the title's page in view did load of "ForYouViewController"
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title = @"Latest";
}
```

After clicking on questions tab (tab bar title changed)

[image]

How can I set the the page title such that it does not alter the tab bar's description?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
YourAppDelegate *appDelegate = (YourAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

[appDelegate tempTabBarItem1] setTitle:@"Questions"];
```

Comment: Potential issue if this is called before the `title` is set on the view controller, the title for the bar item will be replaced by going through the setter for `title`. It may be a good idea to supply the title by overriding `-title`.